# Does applying the transformation $\sum\alpha_{jk}|j,f(k)\rangle\mapsto\sum\omega_N^{-jk}\alpha_{jk}|j,f(k)\rangle$ require computing $f^{-1}$?

Tags: quantum-state

Suppose that I have a bijective function $f: \mathbb{Z}_N → Y$ where $Y$ is a finite set. Suppose that $f$, but not its inverse, can be computed efficiently classically.

I would like to apply the following diagonal unitary transformation:

$$
\sum_{j,k \in \mathbb{Z}_N} \alpha_{j,k} \vert j, f(k) \rangle \mapsto \sum_{j,k \in \mathbb{Z}_N} \omega_N^{-jk} \alpha_{j,k} \vert j, f(k) \rangle.
$$

Here, $\omega_N = e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{N}}$.

My question is: if I want to apply this transformation, does that require $f$ to be inverted classically, or is that not needed because my sum goes over $j$ and $k$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is quantum about that?

Comment: Okay, so more concretely, i have a quantum superposition:

$$\sum_{x_1, x_2 \in X} \alpha_{x_1,x_2} \vert x_1, f(x_2) \rangle$$

And I want to apply a diagonal unitary transformation to get:

$$\sum_{x_1, x_2 \in X} \varphi(x_1,x_2) \alpha_{x_1,x_2} \vert x_1, f(x_2) \rangle$$

My question is, does applying that transformation require inverting the function f classically?

Comment: Before application of the second unitary, there is no entanglement between $x_1$ and $x_2$ in the state $\vert x_1, f(x_2)\rangle$, right?

Comment: No, indeed not.

Comment: It may depend very much on what's known about $\phi(x_1,x_2)$.  For example if $\phi(x_1,x_2)$ is solely dependent on $x_1$, then no need to invert $f(x_2)$.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far!! To be even more concrete, X could be $\mathbb{Z}_N$ and $\varphi(x_1,x_2)$ could be $\omega_N^{-x_1 x_2}$. So, my final question, and then I definitely know my answer, is: even if I sum over $x_2 \in \mathbb{Z}_N$, I would still have to invert the function $f$?

Comment: @Carlo Please focus on *one* question, and add the clarifications to the question.

Comment: You have already 3 reopen votes, at 5 you get the reopen.

Comment: If f is a bijection, f is invertible

Answer (score 1):

In order to apply the conditional rotation by $\omega_{N}^{-jk}$, you will need to know $k$, therefore you will need to have access to both $k$ (for the phase) and $f(k)$ (for the basis vector).

An easier way to see that is to set $N=2$ and let $\alpha_{j,k}$ be $1/2$ for all $i,j$.  There are only two bijective functions $f$ - the identity, or the inverse.

You end up with two different states, depending on whether $f$ is the identity or the inverse.